# LinearLayout at bottom of the screen inside a ScrollView and RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm tring to put a LinearLayout at the bottom of screen inside a ScrollView. The full code is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:fillViewport="false" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/main" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/first" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        >

    <TextView 
        android:gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:id="@id/textView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/second" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

        android:layout_below="@+id/first"
        >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/seperator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:background="#C7C7C7" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seperator"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:textColor="#ff0099cc"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>        
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now, i want that this LinearLayout stay at bottom of screen.

```
<LinearLayout  
    android:id="@+id/myLinear"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:gravity="bottom"
    />
```

I try with android_gravity="bottom" and alignParentBottom and it stay below the others layout but not at bottom.

Comment: You have an awful lot of embedded layouts here.  Can you more fully describe the look you're going for (using plain English).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove ScrollView  and put below LinearLayout inside main Relative Layout

```
     <LinearLayout  
         android:id="@+id/myLinear"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="bottom"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"   
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     />
```

it will appear at bottom of screen.